# How to fix "represents text as a series of Unicode characters" error in C#?

Tags: c#, unicode, discord

I wan't to make a function for my Discord bot that everytime I execute the "|meme" command the bot send a meme from the folder that have the pictures, but says that error: represents text as a series of Unicode characters.

```
   string[] dankMemes;

    public MyBot()
    {
        dankMemes = new string[]
        {
            "dm/1.jpeg";
            "dm/2.jpg";
            "dm/3.jpg";
            "dm/4.jpg";
        };
```

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here to help you. First, please post the exact error message that you get. Secondly, the code posted does not in any way help, it looks like an excerpt from a piece of C# code. Looks OK to me.

Comment: The full message is:
class.System.String
Represents text as a series of Unicode characters.

Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

I only copied the piece of code that I have problem with.

Also, if I put this in my code, all of the code have problems like:
"The name "(name of the variable)" does not exists in the current context.

Comment: At least one problem with your code is that you have placed `;` where you should put `,`, so try fixing that. This has nothing to do with the error message, nor with the code trying to be or talk to a bot, this is basic C# syntax. Specifically I'm talking about the semicolons after each `"dm/1.jpeg"` type of string, place a comma there instead. Does that fix things?

Comment: Yep, putting , instead of ; fixed that, Xedden already answered that, it's my first C# code, so I'm still new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
    string[] dankMemes;

    public MyBot()
    {
        dankMemes = new string[]
        {
            "dm/1.jpeg",
            "dm/2.jpg",
            "dm/3.jpg",
            "dm/4.jpg"
        };
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Xedden! Your answer worked! Thank you very mutch!